# Possible scoping issue

Tags: node.js, backbone.js, socket.io

A possible node.js/backbone.js/socket.io scoping issue I can't wrap my head around.

***(snippet from)*** server.js

```
var app = express();
var server = http.createServer(app);
io = io.listen(server);
```

***(snippet from)*** index.html

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script>
    var socket = io.connect(window.location.origin);
</script>
```

***(snippet from)*** js/views/map.js

```
(function() {  // self invoking anonymous function so we are able to 
               // create the private variable "map" that can be shared here
var map;
var webSocket = window.socket; 

window.MapView = Backbone.View.extend({

initialize: function() {
    this.render();
    webSocket.on("marker dropped", this.propNewMarker);
},

events: {
    "click .dropmarker" : "dropMarker"
},

dropMarker: function(event) {
    console.log("This fires!!!");
    webSocket.emit('marker dropped', { my: 'data' });
},

propNewMarker: function() {
    console.log("someone dropped a marker (im in map.js)");
},
```

***(snippet from)*** MapView.html

```
<a href="#" class="btn btn-primary dropmarker">Drop marker</a>
```

### Behavior I am going for

Clicking on the "dropmarker" button in MapView.html should instigate the webSocket.emit action in dropMarker. (it fires off the console.log without any problems)

### Tested

When I add

```
io.sockets.emit('marker dropped', { 'message': 'ello wurldz' });
```

into server.js, the **propNewMarker** function in **map.js** is fired correctly.

### Preliminary conclusion

It seems that I am struggling with a scoping issue at the level of the buttonclick.
I'm not able to fire a websocket event there.

Any thoughts ? or should I offer more insights in the code before this can be debugged? (tried to keep it as clean as possible)

Comment: When the event is emitted in dropMarker can you check if it is hitting the server? It may be emitting the event which hits the server and then the server must emit an event to hit the client. I am not positive but I don't know if a socket will respond to its own emit on the client.

Comment: thanks for your time JasonM
Answer: No, the event emitted in dropMarker is not showing up in my debug as a websocket (or xhr polling for that matter) 'write' action.

Comment: Just tried a simple example and I know to get propNewMarker called the event has to be emitted from the server. Not sure if that is your full issue but thats part of it. If you have `socket.on('marker dropped', function(msg){socket.emit('marker dropped',msg)});` does it work? Or does the socket still not emit an event when clicking the button?

Comment: if I put <code>socket.on('marker dropped', function(msg){socket.emit('marker dropped',msg)});</code> inside my server.js it works and fires (on click) perfectly.
So, all events towards socket.io have to live on the server(.js) and be fired from there ?

Comment: Essentially. The sockets create a channel between the client and server. When the client emits an event the server gets it. When the server emits an event all clients listening on that socket will get it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't look like an issue with the scope but in fact how you are using the socket

In order for `propNewMarker` to be called the ***server*** must emit a message on `marker dropped`

On the server if you add

```
io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
  socket.on('marker dropped',function(msg){
    socket.emit('marker dropped',msg);
  });
});
```

Then the client should respond just fine to the event. I did some testing and it looks like your scoping is just fine.

Comment: really appreciate the time you put into this issue. Your code snippet + clear explanation as to why your proposed solution works, provided me with a working app + I learned a bit in the process. Thanks again.